# What is the value of the opposing voltage created by the inductor?

Tags: current, inductor

Assume I've connected an inductor to a DC or AC source. The voltage across the inductor due to the source current would be L di/dt. But we know that the inductor induces/creates a voltage to oppose the source voltage. My question is, what is the value of this opposing voltage. Surely it can't be L di/dt because then the opposing voltage and source voltage would be equal thus making current to be zero, right?

Comment: Instantaneously, yes, it is equal and opposing. Then the opposing voltage decays exponentially, allowing an exponentially increasing current flow.

Comment: So intially the opposing voltage is the same as the applied voltage right? What then causes the opposing voltage to decay?

Comment: As I often politely post when welcoming newcomers to the site, this is not an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. The information you're asking for is freely available and well detailed on the interweb. It's all there waiting for you :-) People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own.

Comment: @andy aka yes. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Surely it can't be L di/dt because then the opposing voltage and
> source voltage would be equal thus making current to be zero, right?*

$$\boxed{\text{It's like trying to solve this: }\dfrac{0}{0}}$$

When you apply a steady supply voltage (for example) across a perfect inductor, the back emf equals the applied voltage and, it remains equal to that applied voltage for the length of time that the applied voltage is connected.

On the face of it that appears to prevent current flow into the inductor (which is what I think you are alluding to). This of course appears problematic hence, I believe, this is the reason for your question.

For instance, how can current flow into an inductor when applied voltage and back-emf are equal; we know from the inductor formula that for an applied fixed voltage, V, the rate of change of current is: -

$$\dfrac{di}{dt} = \dfrac{V}{L}$$

But, this seems to be at odds with the back emf exactly equalling the applied emf. But, consider what is happening; the back emf and the applied voltage are both constant values and, they are across a zero ohm impedance hence, the current cannot be defined other than saying: -

$$\boxed{\text{The current is }\dfrac{0}{0}}$$

Why did I say that the impedance is zero? Answer: it's an inductor and, the back-emf is induced in series with that inductor hence with the applied voltage and back-emf voltage being equal, there is 0 volts across the "true" inductance and hence no spectral content across that inductor and, it therefore has to be represented by 0 ohms.

In other words, you cannot use the value of applied voltage and back-emf to calculate the current through the inductor. The current rising or falling delivers the back-emf and that's it.

---

What if the applied voltage is AC - well the difference in voltage between applied and back-emf is still zero and it appears across an impedance of zero ohms so: -

$$\boxed{\text{The current is still }\dfrac{0}{0}}$$

Answer (score 0):

The current is zero but only instantaneously. Inductors give graphs of voltage that upward slope as DC voltage surges and then gradually reaches its set level (which it technically never reaches but gets continually closer). The graph starts at 0V and then ascends. It doesn't immediately leap up to max voltage like a square wave

Answer (score 0):

If you connect an ideal inductor across an ideal DC source, the current is initially zero, and rises **linearly** with time. The voltage, of course, is the applied DC voltage, so the current rises as di/dt = V/L amperes/second.

With an inductor that has some DC resistance, the current does not increase indefinitely but exponentially approaches the applied voltage divided by the resistance with time constant \$\tau = L/R \$. If it's a superconducting coil that has zero DC resistance, it increases linearly until it hits the critical current and then resistance appears.

If sinusoidal AC is applied, the steady-state current is the voltage divided by the reactance, which is   \$X_L = \omega L\$.

Comment: So intially the opposing voltage is the same as the applied voltage right? What then causes the opposing voltage to decay?

Comment: It stays the same (by definition because you've fixed the voltage with your external source) and the current increases.

Comment: Oh so if the opposing voltage remains same and the current increases, does it mean that the resistance or impedance is decreasing?

Comment: There's no resistance in the first case, and I don't think that "impedance" is the best way to think of it, unless the applied voltage is sinusoidal and the steady state (after things have settled down) is what you're after. The frequency components of a unit step are a bit unpleasant and not very intuitive- at least to me (a couple Dirac delta/unit impulse functions).