# Positive Voltage on inductor

Tags: voltage, inductor, oscillator, linear, circuits

I am doing some problems in linear and nonlinear circuit analysis, so I have a question...why is the voltage on an inductor represented as \$V=L\frac{di}{dt}\$ instead of \$V=-L\frac{di}{dt}\$, I know \$-L\frac{di}{dt}\$ is back EMF, but why is voltage written without the minus? Can someone explain?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source? Add a diagram too if possible.

Comment: If current is decreasing then \$\frac{di}{dt}\$ is negative.  As per Andy’s answer, no minus sign needed in the formula  as it is inherently in the \$\frac{di}{dt}\$.

Comment: Also, welcome to EE StackExchange.  Making your post easily readable will help get good responses.  Use [MathJax](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5565/most-common-mathjax-uses-in-electrical-engineering) to format equations nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply a voltage across an inductor, the formula that describes the current flow is this: -

$$V_{APPLIED} = L\cdot\dfrac{di}{dt}$$

So, with 1 volt applied to a 1 henry inductor, the result is a current rising at 1 amp per second. No negative signs were harmed in this formula!

When you induce a voltage (with a changing flux) you put a negative sign in front of the voltage formula to remind us that any current drawn from the terminals will be in a direction that tends to reduce the flux that initially induced the voltage.

---

Given the comments below and the misconceptions about back-emf I have decided to add a few more words about back-emf. What some folk levitate towards is the belief that the back-emf causes the inductor current to ramp up. This is naïve. Consider a pure inductor with 1 volt applied across its terminals. A back-emf of 1 volt is produced and this appears to suggest that current can never flow. However, appearances can be deceptive because we know that current does flow. So, back-emf is a red herring - it exists but it doesn't stop current flowing as per the relationship described earlier in my answer.

But, this seems to be at odds with the back-emf exactly equalling the applied emf. But, consider what is happening; the back-emf and the applied voltage are both constant values and, they are across a zero ohm impedance hence, the current cannot be defined other than saying: -

$$\boxed{\text{The current is: }\hspace{1cm}\dfrac{0}{0}}$$

Why did I say that the impedance is zero?

Answer: it's an inductor and, the back-emf is induced in series with that inductor hence, with the applied voltage and back-emf voltage being equal, there is 0 volts across the "true" inductance. Zero volts means zero spectral content across that inductor and, it therefore has to be represented by 0 ohms.

In other words, you cannot use the value of applied voltage and back-emf to calculate the current through the inductor. The current rising or falling delivers the back-emf and that's it.

Comment: That is not correct.You forgot Lenz's law and I don't think it is a correct way to explain this.

Comment: Ok, but, current increases slow, that slow increasing is because of negative voltage induced by changing magnetic flux...I would be very grateful if You can explain a little bit deeper...

Comment: @Se1fie in what respect is it incorrect?

Comment: Andy the change in current flowing through an inductor creates a back EMF not the other way around.

Comment: @MatijaStankovic the current rise is absolutely and 100% determined by the applied voltage and the inductance. There's nothing else to explain; it's the inductor formula. Go google it or find another source. After all, what else could it mean?

Comment: @Se1fie I agree but what has that got to do with what I've written. I have a good idea - to save a debate on this (not liked because this isn't a forum), you leave an answer on the subject and if you convince me that the inductor formula involving the applied voltage and a perfect inductor is wrong, I'll write "I was an idiot and don't deserve any respect" ten times under the answer I have given. That's got to be worth you making an answer surely.

Comment: 'So, with 1 volt applied to a 1 henry inductor, the result is a current rising at 1 amp per second. No negative signs were harmed in this formula!' The way you write it, it becomes confusing.

Comment: @Se1fie welcome to the world of inductors!

Comment: Andy you confuse the action with the result.

Comment: Ok, if 1 amp is rising through inductor 1H, doesn’t that mean, the NEGATIVE back EMF of 1V will be on inductor to slow rising...I just need to solve a problem without confusion...

Comment: @MatijaStankovic the back-emf is irrelevant - it's a red herring in these circumstances - the back-emf is in opposition to the applied voltage and, it has exactly the same value for a pure inductor so, on that basis might you be inclined to believe that no current can flow?

Comment: @Andy aka, Ok, here is an example, if we have a battery(voltage generator), switch and inductor. If we connect the voltmeter, so we can track the voltage on inductor, voltage will be in V(0)=Vgen, and in some point in time, voltage will decrease to 0? Is that what You want to say?

Comment: @MatijaStankovic that will happen when the linearly rising current reaches a point when Vgen can no longer sustain that current and therefore it collapses the voltage. I don't actually want to say anything that I haven't already said. The formula is as I stated it and, back-emf may seem enticing as some other mechanism but it isn't. Remember that this isn't a forum or a talking shop. If you have a new question about this, please raise it as a new question and give others a chance to respond.

Comment: @MatijaStankovic I have another answer that you may be interested in: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/453752/what-is-the-value-of-the-opposing-voltage-created-by-the-inductor?noredirect=1#comment1384392_453752